# Multidimensional array to string conversion in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, performance, optimization, multidimensional-array

I have to create string like `$zn = "43,49,57,3,68,69";`
from following array without using loop :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            ['pk_id'] => 43
        ),

    [1] => Array
        (
            ['pk_id'] => 49
        ),

    [2] => Array
        (
            ['pk_id'] => 57
        ),

    [3] => Array
        (
            ['pk_id'] => 3
        ),

    [4] => Array
        (
            ['pk_id'] => 68
        ),

    [5] => Array
        (
            ['pk_id'] => 69
        )

);
```

What are the ways I can do?

It should take less time and memory.

Comment: use `array_column` try this https://eval.in/791431

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use array_column with implode function in php

```
implode(',',array_column($a, 'pk_id'));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_walk_recursive` function:

```
$result = array();
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use (&$result) {
    $result[] = $v;
});
echo implode('&', $result);
```

Read more about [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php).